# Incompatibility between the initialState and the AppState using useContext

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reduce, react-context

I have a use contextAPI that seems not working due incompatibility between the InitialState and the AppState. My guess is that something is wrong with `[Field.INPUT]` and `[Field.OUTPUT]`

The initial state:

```
const initialState = { 
  wallet: true, 
  error: '', 
  mod: false,
  independentField: Field.INPUT,
  typedValue: "",
  [Field.INPUT]: {
     //ADDRESS FOR GOERLI WETH
     currencyId: "0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6",
  },
  [Field.OUTPUT]: {
    currencyId: '',
  },
  INPUTVALUE: "",
  OUTPUTVALUE: "",
  pairDataById: {},
  derivedPairDataById: {},
  recipient: undefined,
};
```

The reducer function:

```
function reducer(state: AppState, action: ACTIONTYPE) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "OPEN_WALLET":
      return { 
              wallet: action.payload, 
               error: state.error, 
               mod: state.mod,
               independentFiel: state.independentField,
               typedValue: state.typedValue,
               [Field.INPUT]: { currencyId: state[Field.INPUT].currencyId },
               [Field.OUTPUT]: { currencyId: state[Field.OUTPUT].currencyId },
               INPUTVALUE: state.INPUTVALUE,
               OUTPUTVALUE: state.OUTPUTVALUE,
               pairDataById: state.pairDataById,
               derivedPairDataById: state.pairDataById,
               recipient: state.recipient 

             };
    case "SET_ERROR":
      return { 
            wallet: state.wallet, 
            error: action.payload, 
            mod: state.mod,
            independentFiel: state.independentField,
            typedValue: state.typedValue,
            [Field.INPUT]: { currencyId: state[Field.INPUT].currencyId },
            [Field.OUTPUT]: { currencyId: state[Field.OUTPUT].currencyId },
            INPUTVALUE: state.INPUTVALUE,
            OUTPUTVALUE: state.OUTPUTVALUE,
            pairDataById: state.pairDataById,
            derivedPairDataById: state.pairDataById,
            recipient: state.recipient 
          }
    case 'TOGGLE_MOD':
      return { 
               wallet: state.wallet, 
               error: state.error, 
               mod: action.payload,
               independentFiel: state.independentField,
               typedValue: state.typedValue,
               [Field.INPUT]: { currencyId: state[Field.INPUT].currencyId },
               [Field.OUTPUT]: { currencyId: state[Field.OUTPUT].currencyId },
               INPUTVALUE: state.INPUTVALUE,
               OUTPUTVALUE: state.OUTPUTVALUE,
               pairDataById: state.pairDataById,
               derivedPairDataById: state.pairDataById,
               recipient: state.recipient 
            }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

The app provider:

```
const AppContext = createContext<{
  state: AppState
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<ACTIONTYPE>;
}>({state: initialState, dispatch: () => {} })

export function AppProvider(props: any) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction<any>, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: { wallet: boolean; error: string; mod: boolean; independentField: Field; typedValue: string; INPUT: { currencyId: string; }; OUTPUT: { currencyId: string; }; INPUTVALUE: string; OUTPUTVALUE: string; pairDataById: {}; derivedPairDataById: {}; recipient: undefined; }, action: ACTIONTYPE) => { ...; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction<any>'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: { wallet: boolean; error: string; mod: boolean; independentField: Field; typedValue: string; INPUT: { currencyId: string; }; OUTPUT: { currencyId: string; }; INPUTVALUE: string; OUTPUTVALUE: string; pairDataById: {}; derivedPairDataById: {}; recipient: undefined; }, action: ACTIONTYPE) => { ...; } | { ...; }, initialState: never, initializer?: undefined): [...]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ wallet: boolean; error: string; mod: boolean; independentField: Field; typedValue: string; INPUT: { currencyId: string; }; OUTPUT: { currencyId: string; }; INPUTVALUE: string; OUTPUTVALUE: string; pairDataById: {}; derivedPairDataById: {}; recipient: undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Can someone give me a hint on where i'm messing things?

Comment: What is the definition of `ACTIONTYPE`?

Comment: Just happened to notice a missing `d` at `independentFiel` in the reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the correct return type to `reducer` you get a much better error:

```
function reducer(state: AppState, action: ACTIONTYPE): AppState {
//                                                     ^ added this
```

Which errors here:

```
independentFiel: state.independentField,
```

With:

```
Type
  '{ wallet: boolean; error: string; mod: boolean; independentFiel: Field; typedValue: string; 0: { currencyId: string; }; 1: { currencyId: string; }; INPUTVALUE: string; OUTPUTVALUE: string; pairDataById: {}; derivedPairDataById: {}; recipient: undefined; }'
is not assignable to type
  '{ wallet: boolean; error: string; mod: boolean; independentField: Field; typedValue: string; 0: { currencyId: string; }; 1: { currencyId: string; }; INPUTVALUE: string; OUTPUTVALUE: string; pairDataById: {}; derivedPairDataById: {}; recipient: undefined; }'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, but
  'independentFiel'
does not exist in type
  '{ wallet: boolean; error: string; mod: boolean; independentField: Field; typedValue: string; 0: { currencyId: string; }; 1: { currencyId: string; }; INPUTVALUE: string; OUTPUTVALUE: string; pairDataById: {}; derivedPairDataById: {}; recipient: undefined; }'.

Did you mean to write 'independentField'?(2322)
```

This lets the compiler derive a much nicer error for your because it knows what's expected in a more specific way.

The compiler even offers you the answer at the end there.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/PTAEFp1BbBDBrApqRAPW0AOAbZB3AewCd4JwAoASy2IBdQAlRWAY1oBpQBvUFo52ogDCBAHaDUHUAFcAzoiYATaS0RFQAX1AAzIgWigA5P1a1D5WgE9MyAIKZMAZVqxBoALygrNgttCVRSlpKWGxnV0QLazshABUASQB5ADlYgE0ABQBRD3JQUAAfbi9ogC4jROzkgH0AdVsAGQas2MNOTFhLbAJYRXKAIwICXFhRTTzC4u9EcsNHFuqshgZEhjbQDq6evtBZWiIAgHNx-KKeadnYxIBxa+bqgFlEgBF1ze7egaGRsY1yckQomkBgAYpRENhFNwJvFkhkAKqxdgTRKIhFI8h-EBkCj-FhiPb+QLBULhNyeHgTPChXC0cr7aSITgTNR6IizdYTaAEHbaULyZH5AKKRA2UQi8RgiE7KWQgB0sPRgpKNkUADVQozygAibXKgDassUCrhiIAuuUuBN8qAQLZns8GFlHI5QCDVqBroklg14qBai0ABLW-IsaREfiiFiWeI7bUABlQACEACwgpMggBMAHYAIy5lMAZhBaaT2mzSYAnLnbABWEWKQu5gAc8driBTmf6mcz8ebigAbHqJhoDUa5ajYuiLdCbbxw5Ho7GOcrRzDTbE1Y14VkdcP8pP0VuGju98qOpQiM9XLAkzGdlw1-kRQcAG6IRQZWCX68uO-L7gn1AfgWEoTBwXEcppHFRBtACD9kQ0ABuf5yG0aC2EoMRgI-FQ1AACj2CJynsJwXEEThTCw0QSLiJJUkyLIAEoSIcMlkCtfJZDwIIWAAC1AfCqLEOVpiY2cbRYWB5FAbVKiyGp6iaFptVKEN8n4WhwzGSk5z0vTqWwWlymE0Q5XebZmX06z8lZYhyiIwQ5TsogrJs-TuR2RzEDlTzlXcudhVFQEJVoWUHPInygrFUKjX8gL8mmdVNRmXZItE6JkuwRl4oSw1wXlRVzUtecI0BJcvMi-LpRNac5TDMqo3vTRcoC6r5UPYrigaxd7wiiJ2uNTrYjNeqF3K5qgIS-Iis3bddzSiJasRY8d1a9zhtWhbvInNEVvm9abIvK8b3-SqluO39b3vQ7rJfSh30-b8Tr-PrFqcy7Tpu9SApAsCILpd6fL+8DAXof5ps0FC5ykmTtXmWJFmWVZVJ+zTtOKH79MM4ygblHHECkLG9JckzMJEizejcgLPP6py-OJwKYJisHwrx6KQtZgrFFum0ko1bLUp2-mUt5-JBuWkaSp6iaAO8iXZtGmWmtjFrGZtCXhpnHhlYqunEE1vaRrGxqKrV6bZq2-XJa2sXQE2+brYdk8sjtz7Xrl9L3eu2M7fux6vx-L7PYu56rrOu2QYB62o7B0B1b+GHpOQQwrlue4nleNT9PRogdPjyH8gJwGduL6nptJvGXPLhLadAUzzM6D4efVvSOZgyUCut9vYu5u2+cygWtTxkXBf78Xx0V6XxpV87BAVjclZns2pumw2py6nXl7e+Xxy1k3etV1eEstx28dPl3x-to2rbx521tbudvbO63n++wvQH9j9A5en2558t+vtH42ljpBPGoDwbTUTjaEUfJpDYDpGjQmGNvIjkxHiAk9BSIiHEGgegng+ACGEGICQtAAA8nEgasTIhECYihKCyA6LQfi5QmCmDlM8BhTD+JkNsHRFI6RsgAD4UIaCEfhLg3lygBCCCEMIkVOD0MYa4FhglxLuCEYBTQTF-hoEwHQHQGFgjYVIhkPQr5KAvnwpgPQmBZAmVEJYcSlD8SiEJPqbyiiuEqL4maDwMh5BKDwkQfC-BlCqFckSWRpJIpMRQhMXOYx8Ihl4Q4HBpC5RmIIBYl8oBXwpXcFwHgnjP7eOYQJDQYifpcBsQQOx9U+KUEhJGaB+QyHAGwSQvBmTzGWLUEIiYcTMRAA)

Fix the property name and the errors are resolved:

```
independentField: state.independentField,
```

[See fixed playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/PTAEFp1BbBDBrApqRAPW0AOAbZB3AewCd4JwAoASy2IBdQAlRWAY1oBpQBvUFo52ogDCBAHaDUHUAFcAzoiYATaS0RFQAX1AAzIgWigA5P1a1D5WgE9MyAIKZMAZVqxBoALygrNgttCVRSlpKWGxnV0QLazshABUASQB5ADlYgE0ABQBRD3JQUAAfbi9ogC4jROzkgH0AdVsAGQas2MNOTFhLbAJYRXKAIwICXFhRTTzC4u9EcsNHFuqshgZEhjbQDq6evtBZWiIAgHNx-KKeadnYxIBxa+bqgFlEgBF1ze7egaGRsY1yckQomkBgAYpRENhFNwJvFkhkAKqxdgTRKIhFI8h-EBkCj-FhiPb+QLBULhNyeHgTPChXC0cr7aSITgTNR6IizdYTaAEHbaULyZH5AKKRA2UQi8RgiE7KWQgB0sPRgpKNkUADVQozygAibXKgDassUCrhiIAuuUuBN8qAQLZns8GFlHI5QCDVqBroklg14qBai0ABLW-IsaREfiiFiWeI7bUABlQACEACwgpMggBMAHYAIy5lMAZhBaaT2mzSYAnLnbABWEWKQu5gAc8driBTmf6mcz8ebigAbHqJhoDUa5ajYuiLdCbbxw5Ho7GOcrRzDTbE1Y14VkdcP8pP0VuGju98qOpQiM9XLAkzGdlw1-kRQcAG6IRQZWCX68uO-L7gn1AfgWEoTBwXEcppHFRBtACD9kQ0ABuf5yG0aC2EoMRgI-FQ1AACj2CJynsJwXEEThTCw0QSLiJJUkyLIAEoSIcMlkCtfJZDwIIWAAC1AfCqLEOVpiY2cbRYWB5FAbVKiyGp6iaFptVKEN8n4WhwzGSk5z0vTqWwWlymE0Q5XebZmX06z8lZYhyiIwQ5TsogrJs-TuR2RzEDlTzlXcudhVFQEJVoI0HPInygrFUKjX8gL8mmdVNRmXZItE6JkuwRl4oSw1wXlRVzUtecI0BJcvMi-LpRNac5TDMqo3vTRcoC6r5UPYrigaxd7wiiJ2uNTrYjNeqF3K5qgIS-Iis3bddzSiJasRY8d1a9zhtWhbvInNEVvm9abIvK8b3-SqluO39b3vQ7rJfSh30-b8Tr-PrFqcy7Tpu9SApAsCILpd6fL+8DAXof5ps0FC5ykmTtXmWJFmWVZVJ+zTtOKH79MM4ygblHHECkLG9JckzMJEizejcgLPP6py-OJwKYJisHwrx6KQtZgrFFum0ko1bLUp2-mUt5-JBuWkaSp6iaAO8iXZtGmWmtjFrGZtCXhpnHhlYqunEE1vaRrGxqKrV6bZq2-XJa2sXQE2+brYdk8sjtz7Xrl9L3eu2M7fux6vx-L7PYu56rrOu2QYB62o7B0B1b+GHpOQQwrlue4nleNT9PRogdPjyH8gJwGduL6nptJvGXPLhLadAUzzM6D4efVvSOZgyVuet9vYu5u2+cygWtTxkXBf78Xx0V6XxpV87BAVjclZns2pumw2py6nXl7e+Xxy1k3etV1eEstx28dPl3x-to2rbx521tbudvbO63n++wvQH9j9A5en2558t+vtH42ljpBPGoDwbTUTjaEUfJpDYDpGjQmGNvIjkxHiAk9BSIiHEGgegng+ACGEGICQtAAA8nEgasTIhECYihKCyA6LQfi5QmCmDlM8BhTD+JkNsHRFI6RsgAD4UIaCEfhLg3lygBCCCEMIkVOD0MYa4FhglxLuCEYBTQTF-hoEwHQHQGFgjYVIhkPQr5KAvnwpgPQmBZAmVEJYcSlD8SiEJPqbyiiuEqL4maDwMh5BKDwkQfC-BlCqFckSWRpJIpMRQhMXOYx8Ihl4Q4HBpC5RmIIBYl8oBXwpXcFwHgnjP7eOYQJDQYifpcBsQQOx9U+KUEhJGaB+QyHAGwSQvBmTzGWLUEIiYcTMRAA)